# What is this history data, where is it saved, and how can I interact/delete it?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, browser-history

When I make a text field like this in html, a history drop-down came up, with the first five answers I gave.
What is this data, where is it stored, and how can I delete it?

[image: html text field with drop-down of five history submissions]

Comment: browser autofill

Comment: [See this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the data save in local chorme, your can clear history to delete it or use simple solution here

```html
<form autocomplete="off">

<input type="text" id="text1">

</form>
```

Comment: This won't necessarily work in Chrome. [See this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill)

Comment: It seemed to have worked for me, but I'll make sure not to use it in the future, I'm just testing a little thing right now.